# помогите написать запрос SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день.
Очень нужна Ваша помощь...
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо написать запрос результат которого ответит на вопрос: 
Сколько юзеров на каждом из продуктов в апреле месяце  получили рефанд и удалили продукт, получили рефанд и оставили продукт. (С условием, что анинсталл был позже рефанда)?

То что вышло, но не уверена, что правильно. Посоветуйте что можно изменить для улучшения запроса?

```
SELECT COUNT (user_sales.user_id)
FROM user_sales 
LEFT JOIN user_events ON user_sales.user_id = user_events.user_id, user_sales.product = user_events.product
WHERE user_sales.date = '2016-04'
AND user_sales.payment_status = 'refund'
AND user_events.event = 'uninstall'
AND user_sales.date < user_events.date
GROUP BY user_sales.product
```

Comment: Юлия, что мешает вам сделать это самостоятельно?

Comment: @Юлия, правка не была утверждена, потому, что была произведена с другогой учётной записи. Если модераторы сочтут возможным, учётные записи будут объединены.

Comment: Косяк как минимум тут: _`WHERE user_sales.date = '2016-04'`_